# How to identify what validation rule is invoke invalid event in HTML 5?

Tags: javascript, html, validation

In HTML 5 validation, I can set custom error message using `setCustomValidity()` function, but when I had set attribute `required` for `<input type="email"/>`, is possible set "Please enter your Email." for when invalid event invoked by `required` attribue and "Email format is incorrect." for event invoked by `type="email"` ?

My example form

```
<form>
    <h1>HTML 5 Custom Validation Message</h1>
    <hl>
    Email: <input type="email" id="email" required/> <br>
    Password: <input type="password" id="password" required/> <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

Or [by jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lai32290/82jDm/)

Comment: Looking directly at the Event object suggests that this is impossible. But maybe the hardcore JS folks will know something I don't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `validity` IDL property for the field. It returns a `ValidityState` object, containing the following properties:

- badInput
- customError
- patternMismatch
- rangeOverflow
- rangeUnderflow
- stepMismatch
- tooLong
- typeMismatch
- valid
- valueMissing

Each property's value will be either `true` or `false`, based on the type of error. In the case of an email address, an invalid email address would make `validity.typeMatch` `true`, and all other properties `false`. A missing email address would set `validity.valueMissing` `true`, and all other properties `false`.

Using jQuery, that would be:

```
$("#email").on('invalid', function(e){
    var msg;
    if(e.target.validity.valueMissing){
      msg = 'Your email address is missing';
    }
    if(e.target.validity.typeMismatch){
      msg = 'Your email address is invalid';
    }
    e.target.setCustomValidity(msg);
});
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/Bkz2M/).